# "Learn more" button is not working in my html code

Tags: html

```html
<!DOCTYPE.html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    </head>
    <body>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="/home/heisenberg/Documents/GitHub/Scifi.github.io/heisenberg.svg" width="30" height="30" alt="">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="About.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="Blog.html">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Content
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">soon..</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">soon..</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">soon..</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul>
                    </ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul>
                    </ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://github.com/heisenberg01010">
                            <img src="/home/heisenberg/Documents/GitHub/Scifi.github.io/social-media.svg" width="30" height="30" alt="">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jai-lodha-3b63b4197/">
                            <img src="/home/heisenberg/Documents/GitHub/Scifi.github.io/logos.svg" width="30" height="30" alt="">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.instagram.com/mai_jai_/">
                            <img src="/home/heisenberg/Documents/GitHub/Scifi.github.io/brands-and-logotypes.svg" width="30" height="30" alt="">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="text-black shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded"><strong>Scroll across some beautiful snaps of The Hubble telescope!!</strong></div>
        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="/home/heisenberg/Documents/GitHub/Scifi.github.io/bubble nebula.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                        <h1 class="display-4">The Bubble Nebula!</h1>
                        <hr class="my-4">
                        <a class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" href="https://hubblesite.org/image/3725/gallery" role="button">Learn more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="/home/heisenberg/Documents/GitHub/Scifi.github.io/Sombero galaxy.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                        <h1 class="display-4">The Sombrero Galaxy!</h1>
                        <hr class="my-4">
                        <a class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" href="https://hubblesite.org/contents/media/images/2003/28/1415-Image.html"  role="button">Learn more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="/home/heisenberg/Documents/GitHub/Scifi.github.io/heic1501a.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                        <h1 class="display-4">The Pillars Of Creation!</h1>
                        <hr class="my-4">
                        <a class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" href="https://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/the-pillars-of-creation" role="button">Learn more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried my best but the "Learn more" button is not working under
`<div class= "jumbotron">`. There are three such buttons working under the carousel. I am using bootstrap to build a site. I think some properties are overlapping. I have used jumbotron from here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/jumbotron/. I have used carousel from here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/. Earlier there was no problem. I don't know how this bug came.
Please suggest some changes.

Comment: because you have add href to the button nothing else you are doing with it So  what exactly you want to do with learn more button?

Comment: What happens when you click the buttons that don't work, and what should happen in theory? Also, you do a fairly good job with accessibility, but please give meaningful alt text to your images, and make sure attributes like "aria-expanded" change when appropriate.

Comment: @Saad Sohail  I have added a link in href attribute to a hubble telescope site.

Comment: @TimB. Those learn more buttons are acting as links to external websites.

Comment: did you have Bootstrap 4 with the working files? Because the button is working fine out the div of images !!! So there is no issue with the code

Comment: @SaadSohail  yes i am using bootstrap 4.4 using this link <https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Problem is with the bootstrap files, you don't have the files of bootstrap 4, 
if you have add the all links and bootstrap link to the head of html then it will work.

I have modified the code somehow so you can have the idea. !!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
        <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra
            attention to featured content or information.</p>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger
            container.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="https://hubblesite.org/image/3725/gallery" role="button">Learn more</a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: You added the elements with **jumbotron** class inside of carousel items. And this caused to place the elements with **jumbotron** class to be placed under the **carousel controls**. 
I suggest to change the bottom of the carousel controls.

To fix the problem, add this script:

```
<script>
    const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('jumbotron')[0]);
    const bottomOfCarouselAction = +computedStyle.getPropertyValue('height').replace('px', '') + +computedStyle.getPropertyValue('margin-top').replace('px', '') + +computedStyle.getPropertyValue('margin-bottom').replace('px', '');
    document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-control-prev')[0].style.bottom = bottomOfCarouselAction;        //set the bottom property of carousel previous control to the top of the jumbotron. 
    document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-control-next')[0].style.bottom = bottomOfCarouselAction;        //set the bottom property of carousel next control to the top of the jumbotron. 
</script>
```